# Migrate .NET Framework 4 project to netcoreapp1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created .net core web application whose framework is netcoreapp1.0. 
In newly created web application, I want to add reference of another project whose .NET Framework version is 4.

To fix this what I am doing is, I have created a new .net core class library, and copying my code from Framework 4 project to this new project, and then adding reference to .net core web application.

I am required to this because, "netcoreapp1.0" framework is not getting populated in project properties.

[image]

Is project recreation is only way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use your .csproj class library as a .net core class library for now. You have to create a new projectlike you did.

But the .xproj/project.json system is going to disappear in favor of .csproj/msbuild (annoucement [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/)) so maybe in the future a .net4/.csproj library will have the possibility to become a .netcore/.csproj libray.

Comment: No, he won't **EVER** be able to add .NET 4 class library to a .NET Core application. .NET Core is based on `System.Runtime` (first used in Windows 8.0 and Windows 8.0 Mobile). And this has only be added in .NET 4.5, hence the lowest possible target is .NET 4.5

Comment: Yes i know, but we may be able in the future to retarget a .NET class library to a .NET Standard class library (like we can do from .NET4 to .NET4.5 for example).